# How to find if the topic is mentioned in the sentence ? - nlp

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am pretty new to NLP, and I am looking for the most appropriate solution for my problem.

In simplification, I want to create a "tag list" from the title.

Tags are predefined, and I can easily label examples for training.

**Simple examples:**

> Format "exemplary sentence" - "exemplary tag list"

- "The biggest elephant in the world" - [Animals]
- "I like mangos and gorillas" - [Animals, Fruits]
- "I have 3 cats and 4 dogs" - [Animals]
- "I have diabetes" - [Diseases]
- "I don't have diabetes but I have a cat" - [Animals]

I don't need the specific value of the tag

e.g. `tags = { Animal: Elephant }` is as useful as `tags = [Animals]`

I could find the only solutions that extract the entity. I only came up with a building list of matcher and then trying them all, is there any clever and performant way to do it?

Thanks for any suggestions, tips, and resources, Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your own custom classifier (as suggested by polm23), but given that you are new to NLP this might be too complicated and time consuming.

An **exciting new way of doing this is with so-called "zero-shot classification"**. This basically means that you take a general machine learning model that has been pre-trained by someone else in a very general way for text classification and you simply apply it to your specific use case without having to train/fine-tune it. The [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/) Transformers library has a very easy to use implementation of this. Here is an interactive [web application](https://huggingface.co/zero-shot/) to see what it does without coding. Here is a [Jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jocViLorbwWIkTXKwxCOV9HLTaDDgCaw?usp=sharing) which demonstrates how to use it in Python. You can just copy-paste code from the notebook.

**Concretely applied to your use-case, this would look something like this:**

```
# pip install transformers==3.1.0  # pip install in terminal
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")

sequence = "The biggest elephant in the world"
candidate_labels = ["animals", "fruits", "diseases"]

classifier(sequence, candidate_labels)

# output: {'sequence': 'The biggest elephant in the world', 
# 'labels': ['animals', 'diseases', 'fruits'], 
# 'scores': [0.9948041439056396, 0.0035726651549339294, 0.0016232384368777275]}
```

If you want that the algorithm attributes more than one label to the text, you can activate multi-label classification and it will consider more than one label per text.

```
sequence = "I like mangos and gorillas"
candidate_labels = ["animals", "fruits", "diseases"]

classifier(sequence, candidate_labels, multi_class=True)

# output: {'sequence': 'I like mangos and gorillas', 
# 'labels': ['animals', 'fruits', 'diseases'], 
# 'scores': [0.9978452920913696, 0.989518404006958, 0.00015786082076374441]}
```

=> **In your words**: It "creates a 'tag list' " for each text. i.e. For each of the predefined tags, it provides a confidence score and you can then just select the tags with the highest confidence score for your 'true tags list'.

I tested it and the actual outputs are in the code above. It classified everything correctly :)

It tried it on other use cases and it's not 100% accurate, but it's pretty good, given the fact that the code is super simple and you don't have to train a model yourself.
Here are [details on the theory](https://joeddav.github.io/blog/2020/05/29/ZSL.html), if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called **multi-label classification**. Your "tags" are **labels**, and each document can have more than one of them.

A typical way to implement this is to train a binary classifier for each label, and then consider the labels that are above a threshold in their predictions to be positive.

spaCy supports multi-label classification. It's not called out in [the tutorial for textcat](https://spacy.io/usage/training#textcat), but you can add more classes than POS and NEG and it should be able to learn them.